# Tasker | Intent Received | access Extras via tasker variables

Tags: tasker, intents

I have Tasker send an Intent to Weather Ace then listens for an Intent Received. Upon receiving the responding Broadcast Intent from Weather Ace, the Extra fields are supposed to be available via local Tasker %variables but when I try to flash them to the screen, something goes wrong.

I do get a flash to the screen but it seems that all the variables are empty except some indices in the %evtprm() array.

Here's my triggering task, the listening profile, and the flashing task:

---

DESCRIPTION FORMAT

```
Weather Ace: Send Weather Data (79)
    A1: Send Intent [ Action:mycodefab.aleph.weather.WEATHER_DATA Cat:None Mime Type: Data: Extra: Extra: Extra: Package: Class: Target:Broadcast Receiver ] 

Profile: Weather Ace: Weather Data (9)
    Event: Intent Received [ Action:mycodefab.aleph.weather.WEATHER_DATA Cat:None Cat:None Scheme:* Mime Type:* ]
Enter: Weather Ace: Response Handler (27)
    A1: JavaScriptlet [ Code:var nl = "\n";

var output = "";

output =  `intent_data: ${
    local("%intent_data") + nl
}`;

var forEachCount = 0;

evtprm.forEach(
    function(item){

        forEachCount++

        output += `Event Param ${

            forEachCount

        }: ${

            item + nl

        }`;

    }
);

output += `request_tag: ${
    local("%request_tag") + nl
}`;

output += `error_desc: ${
    local("%error_desc") + nl
}`;

output += `api_version: ${
    local("%api_version") + nl
}`;

output += `place_name: ${
    local("%place_name") + nl
}`;

output += `place_lon: ${
    local("%place_lon") + nl
}`;

output += `place_lat: ${
    local("%place_lat") + nl
}`;

output += `place_autofollow: ${
    local("%place_autofollow") + nl
}`;

output += `is_day: ${
    local("%is_day") + nl
}`;

output += `updated: ${
    local("%updated") + nl
}`;

output += `weather_desc: ${
    local("%weather_desc") + nl
}`;

output += `type: ${
    local("%type") + nl
}`;

output += `current: ${
    local("%current") + nl
}`;

output += `datetime: ${
    local("%datetime") + nl
}`;

output += `temp_max: ${
    local("%temp_max") + nl
}`;

output += `temp_min: ${
    local("%temp_min") + nl
}`;

output += `pressure: ${
    local("%pressure") + nl
}`;

output += `humidity: ${
    local("%humidity") + nl
}`;

output += `windspeed: ${
    local("%windspeed") + nl
}`;

output += `windspeed: ${
    local("%windspeed") + nl
}`;

output += `windspeed_gusts: ${
    local("%windspeed_gusts") + nl
}`;

output += `weather_id: ${
    local("%weather_id") + nl
}`;

output += `dewpoint_max: ${
    local("%dewpoint_max") + nl
}`;

output += `dewpoint_min: ${
    local("%dewpoint_min") + nl
}`;

output += `sunrise: ${
    local("%sunrise") + nl
}`;

output += `sunset: ${
    local("%sunset") + nl
}`;

output += `wind_degree: ${
    local("%wind_degree") + nl
}`;

output += `precipitation: ${
    local("%precipitation") + nl
}`;

output += `pop: ${
    local("%pop") + nl
}`;

output += `cloudiness: ${
    local("%cloudiness") + nl
}`;

output += `uvi: ${
    local("%uvi") + nl
}`;

output += `visibility: ${
    local("%visibility") + nl
}`;

output += `feelslike_max: ${
    local("%feelslike_max") + nl
}`;

output += `feelslike_min: ${
    local("%feelslike_min") + nl
}`;

output += `name: ${
    local("%name") + nl
}`;

output += `coords: ${
    local("%coords") + nl
}`;

output += `autofollow: ${
    local("%autofollow") + nl
}`;

output += `timezone: ${
    local("%timezone") + nl
}`;

flashLong(output); Libraries: Auto Exit:On Timeout (Seconds):45 ]
```

---

XML FORMAT Firing Task

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="5.7.1">
    <Task sr="task79">
        <cdate>1556200360404</cdate>
        <edate>1557607436237</edate>
        <id>79</id>
        <nme>Weather Ace: Send Weather Data</nme>
        <pri>100</pri>
        <Action sr="act0" ve="7">
            <code>877</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">mycodefab.aleph.weather.WEATHER_DATA</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg2" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg9" val="0"/>
        </Action>
    </Task>
</TaskerData>
```

XML FORMAT Listener Profile

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="5.7.1">
    <Profile sr="prof9" ve="2">
        <cdate>1557374196351</cdate>
        <edate>1557605085547</edate>
        <id>9</id>
        <mid0>27</mid0>
        <nme>Weather Ace: Weather Data</nme>
        <Event sr="con0" ve="2">
            <code>599</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">mycodefab.aleph.weather.WEATHER_DATA</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
        </Event>
    </Profile>
    <Task sr="task27">
        <cdate>1555907929554</cdate>
        <edate>1557605755446</edate>
        <id>27</id>
        <nme>Weather Ace: Response Handler</nme>
        <pri>6</pri>
        <Action sr="act0" ve="7">
            <code>129</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">var nl = "\n";

var output = "";

output =  `intent_data: ${
    local("%intent_data") + nl
}`;

var forEachCount = 0;

evtprm.forEach(
    function(item){

        forEachCount++

        output += `Event Param ${

            forEachCount

        }: ${

            item + nl

        }`;

    }
);

output += `request_tag: ${
    local("%request_tag") + nl
}`;

output += `error_desc: ${
    local("%error_desc") + nl
}`;

output += `api_version: ${
    local("%api_version") + nl
}`;

output += `place_name: ${
    local("%place_name") + nl
}`;

output += `place_lon: ${
    local("%place_lon") + nl
}`;

output += `place_lat: ${
    local("%place_lat") + nl
}`;

output += `place_autofollow: ${
    local("%place_autofollow") + nl
}`;

output += `is_day: ${
    local("%is_day") + nl
}`;

output += `updated: ${
    local("%updated") + nl
}`;

output += `weather_desc: ${
    local("%weather_desc") + nl
}`;

output += `type: ${
    local("%type") + nl
}`;

output += `current: ${
    local("%current") + nl
}`;

output += `datetime: ${
    local("%datetime") + nl
}`;

output += `temp_max: ${
    local("%temp_max") + nl
}`;

output += `temp_min: ${
    local("%temp_min") + nl
}`;

output += `pressure: ${
    local("%pressure") + nl
}`;

output += `humidity: ${
    local("%humidity") + nl
}`;

output += `windspeed: ${
    local("%windspeed") + nl
}`;

output += `windspeed: ${
    local("%windspeed") + nl
}`;

output += `windspeed_gusts: ${
    local("%windspeed_gusts") + nl
}`;

output += `weather_id: ${
    local("%weather_id") + nl
}`;

output += `dewpoint_max: ${
    local("%dewpoint_max") + nl
}`;

output += `dewpoint_min: ${
    local("%dewpoint_min") + nl
}`;

output += `sunrise: ${
    local("%sunrise") + nl
}`;

output += `sunset: ${
    local("%sunset") + nl
}`;

output += `wind_degree: ${
    local("%wind_degree") + nl
}`;

output += `precipitation: ${
    local("%precipitation") + nl
}`;

output += `pop: ${
    local("%pop") + nl
}`;

output += `cloudiness: ${
    local("%cloudiness") + nl
}`;

output += `uvi: ${
    local("%uvi") + nl
}`;

output += `visibility: ${
    local("%visibility") + nl
}`;

output += `feelslike_max: ${
    local("%feelslike_max") + nl
}`;

output += `feelslike_min: ${
    local("%feelslike_min") + nl
}`;

output += `name: ${
    local("%name") + nl
}`;

output += `coords: ${
    local("%coords") + nl
}`;

output += `autofollow: ${
    local("%autofollow") + nl
}`;

output += `timezone: ${
    local("%timezone") + nl
}`;

flashLong(output);</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="45"/>
        </Action>
        <Img sr="icn" ve="2">
            <nme>hd_action_help</nme>
        </Img>
    </Task>
</TaskerData>
```

XML FORMAT Listener Profile Task

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="5.7.1">
    <Task sr="task27">
        <cdate>1555907929554</cdate>
        <edate>1557605755446</edate>
        <id>27</id>
        <nme>Weather Ace: Response Handler</nme>
        <pri>6</pri>
        <Action sr="act0" ve="7">
            <code>129</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">var nl = "\n";

var output = "";

output =  `intent_data: ${
    local("%intent_data") + nl
}`;

var forEachCount = 0;

evtprm.forEach(
    function(item){

        forEachCount++

        output += `Event Param ${

            forEachCount

        }: ${

            item + nl

        }`;

    }
);

output += `request_tag: ${
    local("%request_tag") + nl
}`;

output += `error_desc: ${
    local("%error_desc") + nl
}`;

output += `api_version: ${
    local("%api_version") + nl
}`;

output += `place_name: ${
    local("%place_name") + nl
}`;

output += `place_lon: ${
    local("%place_lon") + nl
}`;

output += `place_lat: ${
    local("%place_lat") + nl
}`;

output += `place_autofollow: ${
    local("%place_autofollow") + nl
}`;

output += `is_day: ${
    local("%is_day") + nl
}`;

output += `updated: ${
    local("%updated") + nl
}`;

output += `weather_desc: ${
    local("%weather_desc") + nl
}`;

output += `type: ${
    local("%type") + nl
}`;

output += `current: ${
    local("%current") + nl
}`;

output += `datetime: ${
    local("%datetime") + nl
}`;

output += `temp_max: ${
    local("%temp_max") + nl
}`;

output += `temp_min: ${
    local("%temp_min") + nl
}`;

output += `pressure: ${
    local("%pressure") + nl
}`;

output += `humidity: ${
    local("%humidity") + nl
}`;

output += `windspeed: ${
    local("%windspeed") + nl
}`;

output += `windspeed: ${
    local("%windspeed") + nl
}`;

output += `windspeed_gusts: ${
    local("%windspeed_gusts") + nl
}`;

output += `weather_id: ${
    local("%weather_id") + nl
}`;

output += `dewpoint_max: ${
    local("%dewpoint_max") + nl
}`;

output += `dewpoint_min: ${
    local("%dewpoint_min") + nl
}`;

output += `sunrise: ${
    local("%sunrise") + nl
}`;

output += `sunset: ${
    local("%sunset") + nl
}`;

output += `wind_degree: ${
    local("%wind_degree") + nl
}`;

output += `precipitation: ${
    local("%precipitation") + nl
}`;

output += `pop: ${
    local("%pop") + nl
}`;

output += `cloudiness: ${
    local("%cloudiness") + nl
}`;

output += `uvi: ${
    local("%uvi") + nl
}`;

output += `visibility: ${
    local("%visibility") + nl
}`;

output += `feelslike_max: ${
    local("%feelslike_max") + nl
}`;

output += `feelslike_min: ${
    local("%feelslike_min") + nl
}`;

output += `name: ${
    local("%name") + nl
}`;

output += `coords: ${
    local("%coords") + nl
}`;

output += `autofollow: ${
    local("%autofollow") + nl
}`;

output += `timezone: ${
    local("%timezone") + nl
}`;

flashLong(output);</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="45"/>
        </Action>
        <Img sr="icn" ve="2">
            <nme>hd_action_help</nme>
        </Img>
    </Task>
</TaskerData>
```

Comment: Anybody out there?